# How can a chemical substance explode, producing only solid products?

Tags: physical-chemistry, explosions

[Silver acetilyde](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_acetylide), like some other salts of silver, is unstable and explodes with great force. However, unlike almost all other explosive compounds, it doesn't produce any gases - it only produces silver and carbon (graphite?) dust.

So how come it can explode at all, when, I guess, the volume of the solids before and after the reaction is almost the same?

Comment: The Wikipedia page that you linked to doesn't say that that stuff "explodes with great force." It _does_ says that that stuff is a "high explosive," which means that it _[detonates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Detonation)_. A detonation can be very destructive to material that is in intimate contact with the explosive even if there is no accompanying "blast."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The chemical reaction is exothermic. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F_TIVJS-lFc) explains that the explosions are due to rapid heating of the surrounding air.